# Problems with the serializer validator do not allow data to be sent

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

In this question, I had a problem to pass the user to the serializer, which was solved, but now I face another problem that the serializer validator stops sending user information and thinks I am going to create a new user.

views.py

```
class ProfileView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=model_to_dict(request.user))
        if serializer.is_valid():
            return successful_response(
                messages=_('User Profile'),
                data=serializer.data
            )
        return unsuccessful_response(errors=serializer.errors, status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

My user model class:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    .....
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    ....
```

errors:

```
{
    "errors": {
        "email": [
            "user with this email address already exists."
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried passing data=model_to_dict(request.data) instead of data=model_to_dict(request.user) to the serializer_class method?

Answer (score 0):

I realized where the problem was, I should have used get_serializer instead of get_serializer_class. In this case, there is no need for validation.

```
class ProfileView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(request.user)
        return successful_response(
            messages=_('User Profile'),
            data=serializer.data
        )
```